# How to add Multiple Categories in the SendGrid Email in C#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

How to add multiple categories in the sendgrid smtp api in c#? If I use the below code to add the category :

1.) var message=SendGrid.GetInstance();

2.) message.Header.SetCategory(“EmailName”);

It adds the "EmailName" as category successfully. If I need to add multiple categories and write the second step statement multiple times then it creates only the last category and overrides the previous categories.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding multiple categories isn't supported by the SendGrid C# library at the moment. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/30) on github for this problem. It's a small fix so if you want to fork the repo it would be easy to do this change yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Looking for same thing as OP via google and stumbled on this question. It looks like SendGrid C# library now supports multiple categories, so thought I'd add it here in case others stumble here too.

```
IEnumerable<string> categories = new string[] { "c1", "c2" };
message.Header.SetCategories(categories);
```

Link to github issue where this was resolved:

- https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/pull/31

Comment: This is the correct answer now. There's also a SetCategory method for single categories.